# Как сделать задержку ровно в 1мс ассемблерной вставкой?

Tags: c++, winapi, ассемблер

В общем проблема следующая,в моем коде необходимо чтоб пауза длилась ровно 1 мс,но когда я использую средства с++,типо `Sleep()` или `sleep_for` то задержка каждого sleep на 1мс больше.Более того ,на разных Windows она разная.Так вот может быть с ассемблерной вставкой получится сделать более точную паузу,которая будет работать на всех windows(7-10) одинаково?Только я совершенно не знаю assembler,и как это сделать.

Comment: "Более того ,на разных Windows она разная" - можно ознакомиться, как она зависит от версии Windows? И вам же уже отвечали - это не та операционная система, которая в состоянии обеспечить точные задержки. Попробуйте действовать как обычно, но задрать по максимуму приоритет своего процесса - только непонятно, зачем вам такая точность?...

Comment: если я пишу ивент на перемещение мыши,например на 80 пикселей вниз,и паузу после него в 100мс,а потом мне надо чтоб мышь не резко перемещалась а плавно,разложу на более маленькие перемещения,тог время затраченое на перемещение будет другим.Я делаю макрос для игры,там 1мс это заметно,особенно когда она складывается у 1000 ивентов и молучается дикая задержка

Comment: Странно это вообще, пытаться управлять курсором пользователя.

Answer (score 5):

`call Sleep` годится? :)

Попробуйте изменить подход. `Sleep` передает управление другим потокам. Попробуйте в цикле постоянно опрашивать время, и как закончится нужное время - идите дальше. Конечно, загрузка проца вырастет, но точность должна быть повыше из-за мениьшего количества переключений.

В С++ - используя [`high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) или `QueryPerformanceCounter` из WinnAPI.

Comment: а можете помочь?я просто не умею с шаблонами работать.Я хочу попробовать сделать функцию куда я буду передавать значение задержки,складывать с текущим временем и в цикле проверять когда текущее время станет больше суммы.Но у меня не получается сложить,потому что там шаблон